# TagCanvas doesn't appear in my second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tagcanvas

I have two `divs`, one it´s the home page, and another is to other page that is showed and the home page is hided. My problem is that when the second div is showed the tag canvas doesn't appear.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          setTimeout(function() { window.onload(); }, 700);
          window.onload = function() {
            try {
              TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas','tags',{
                textFont: 'Impact,"Arial Black",sans-serif',
                textHeight: 25,
                textColour: '#ff0000',
                outlineColour: '#ff00ff',
                reverse: true,
                depth: 0.8,
                maxSpeed: 0.05,
                shape: "sphere",
                dragControl: true,
                txtOpt: true

              });
            } catch(e) {
              // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
              document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
            }
          };
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
          setTimeout(function() { window.onload(); }, 700);
          window.onload = function() {
            try {
              TagCanvas.Start('myCanvasSele','tagsSele',{
                textFont: 'Impact,"Arial Black",sans-serif',
                textHeight: 25,
                textColour: '#ff0000',
                outlineColour: '#ff00ff',
                reverse: true,
                depth: 0.8,
                maxSpeed: 0.05,
                shape: "sphere",
                dragControl: true,
                txtOpt: true

              });
            } catch(e) {
              // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
              document.getElementById('myCanvasContainerSele').style.display = 'none';
            }
          };
        </script>
    ...
    <!---------- Home Page -------->
    <div class="container" id="index">
        <div class="starter-template">

            <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px">
                <div id="myCanvasContainer">
                    <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvas">
                    </canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="tags">
                    <ul id="tagList">
    <li>Messi</li>
    <li>Cristiano Ronaldo</li>
    <li>Bale</li>
    <li>Neymar</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    ...

    <!-------------- Page of Teams ---------->
    <div class="container" id="selecoes">
        <div class="starter-template">

            <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px">
                <div id="myCanvasContainerSele">
                    <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvasSele">
                    </canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="tagsSele">
                    <ul id="tagListSele">
    <li>Portugal</li>
    <li>Brazil</li>
    <li>France</li>
    <li>England</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I click, for example, in Messi the page of Teams (is the second div) is showed and the Home page is hided, but the tag canvas doesn't appears unlike the home page.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. You can probably use classes here instead.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to rename id's. But the error still happens.

Comment: anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? In the second TagCanvas only appears the list, the tag will not appear.

Comment: @user3658717 - can you share a JSFiddle? Do you have any info in console?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I think I figured out what you wanted to achieve assuming you are using [tagcanvas.js](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // I created 2 functions that are called on the click of the links I added
      showIndexPage = function() {

        //When home is clicked we hide the teams page if it is not already done and show the home page, then execute the TagCanvas.Start
        document.getElementById('teams').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('index').style.display = 'block';
        try {
          TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas','tags',{
            textFont: 'Impact,"Arial Black",sans-serif',
            textHeight: 25,
            textColour: '#ff0000',
            outlineColour: '#ff00ff',
            reverse: true,
            depth: 0.8,
            maxSpeed: 0.05,
            shape: "sphere",
            dragControl: true,
            txtOpt: true

          });
        } catch(e) {
          // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
          document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
        }
      };

      showTeamPage = function() {

        //When teams is clicked we hide the home page if it is not already done and show the teams page, then execute the TagCanvas.Start
        document.getElementById('index').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('teams').style.display = 'block';
        try {
          TagCanvas.Start('myCanvasTeams','tagsTeams',{
            textFont: 'Impact,"Arial Black",sans-serif',
            textHeight: 25,
            textColour: '#ff0000',
            outlineColour: '#ff00ff',
            reverse: true,
            depth: 0.8,
            maxSpeed: 0.05,
            shape: "sphere",
            dragControl: true,
            txtOpt: true

          });
        } catch(e) {
          // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
          document.getElementById('myCanvasContainerTeams').style.display = 'none';
        }
      };
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:" onclick="showIndexPage()">Home</a>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="showTeamPage()">Teams</a>

    <div class="container" id="index" style="display: none;">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px">
                <div id="myCanvasContainer">
                 <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvas">
                  <p>Anything in here will be replaced on browsers that support the canvas element</p>
                 </canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="tags">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Messi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cristiano Ronaldo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bale</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Neymar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="teams" style="display: none;">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px">
                <div id="myCanvasContainerTeams">
                 <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvasTeams">
                  <p>Anything in here will be replaced on browsers that support the canvas element</p>
                 </canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="tagsTeams">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">England</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I changed the html code from the team page so it matches the one from the index exactly, but changed the IDs so they are all unique. The problem that I found trying to recreate the bug what that the second time you were calling TagCanvas.Start(... overwritted the first one, also I had to put anchor tags in the tags list so it would work. [Here you can see it in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfJom)